# How to return to the main page after making a payment on PayBox, with VAADIN?

Tags: vaadin

I would like to return to my main page after making a payment.
I have a return parameter in my url that is zero until I went to the payment site and I did not validate my payment.
After payment, therefore non-zero return parameter (ex:  http://localhost:8080/app0/#!retour?retour=APP:337:2:/QSYS.LIB/CMT31.LIB/PAMWTRCL8.PGM&mt=3000&code=00000&key=krE0CVCuH%2FQ1fw2iOEIt6xYVqdmcUjiUNg2n9oSHcL2UkaE7N5WyzargWQS85u7IKNH6m38zuN3qXcx42KqEfXIiem1MHyfdQdamqzKfCP25Jwze7PPhGBjXSzO4JkKi2Pp2w573XKAwBFMkuaLcBeFb3Uq1qvWyRumYdk89Sro%3D), 
I would like to return to my main page.
My problem is that this parameter is not zero, so I can not go back to the main page. My solution would be to use the fragments but I do not know how to do it. Could you help me.

```
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
    String retour=(String) vaadinRequest.getParameter("retour");
    if(retour!=null) {
        String mt=(String) vaadinRequest.getParameter("mt");
        String code=(String) vaadinRequest.getParameter("code");
        String key=(String) vaadinRequest.getParameter("key");
        traiteRetourPaiement(retour, mt, code, key);
    } else {
        String nomApp = getNomApp(vaadinRequest);
        setContent(new DynamicView(nomApp));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the parameters are in the fragment part of the URI, i.e. after the `#` character. This part of the URI is available through `getPage().getLocation().getFragment()`, but only as a long string and not split up into individual parameters.

Alternatively, you can maybe change how the PayBox return URI is created so that there isn't any `#` character there. In that case, the values would be available as regular request parameters in the way that your example code tries to access them.